# Django extremely slow page loads when using remote database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a working Django application that is running locally using an sqlite3 database without problem. However, when I change the Django database settings to use my external AWS RDS database all my pages start taking upwards of 40 seconds to load. I have checked my AWS metrics and my instance is not even close to being fully utilized. When I make a request to a view with no database read/write operations I also get the same problem. My activity monitor shows my local CPU spiking with each request. It shows a process named 'WindowsServer' using most of the CPU during each request.

I am aware more latency is expected when using a remote database but I don't think this should result in 40 second page lags. What other problems that could be causing this behaviour?

AWS database monitoring
[image]

Local machine
[image]

Comment: where is you server?

Comment: I am running my app locally. My database is running from (southeast-2/sydney aws region).

Comment: did you find the answer, I am also facing similar issue

Comment: No my app runs normally when deployed to Beanstalk so I just made a staging database locally to test all my changes without having to worry about the painful latency

Comment: Yes, it works fine when deployed to EBS, problem is only when it running locally and connecting to remote DB

Answer (score 1):

So your computer has connection to the server in Amazon, that's the problem with latency. Production servers should be in the same place as DB servers(or should have very very good connection, so the latency is lowered as much as possible.)

--edit--

So we need more details. What is your ISP? What is your connection properties? Uplink, downlink? What are pings to servers in AWS?

Comment: I am aware, but this simply cannot explain 40 second latencies. I have benchmarked with my other apps using the same set up they have not even come close to this.